# Date tuples in python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

Iv'e got the following hardcoded list of tuples:

```
                dates = [
                    ('2020-01', '2020-02'),
                    ('2020-02', '2020-03'),
                    ('2020-03', '2020-04'),
                    ('2020-04', '2020-05'),
                    ('2020-05', '2020-06'),
                    ('2020-06', '2020-07'),
                    ('2020-07', '2020-08'),
                    ('2020-08', '2020-09'),
                    ('2020-09', '2020-10'),
                    ('2020-11', '2020-12'),
                    ('2020-12', '2021-01'),
                    ('2021-01', '2021-02'),
                    ('2021-02', '2021-03'),
                    ('2021-03', '2021-04'),
                    ('2021-04', '2021-05'),
                    ('2021-05', '2021-06'),
                    ('2021-06', '2021-07'),
                    ('2021-07', '2021-08'),
                    ('2021-08', '2021-09'),
                    ('2021-09', '2021-10'),
                    ('2021-11', '2021-12'),
                    ('2021-12', '2022-01'),
                    ('2022-01', '2022-02'),
                ]
```

Assuming we were in January 2022, this list packs a tuples of ("from_date", "to_date") of 2 consecutive years (going back).

I was wondering if there's a way of getting this dates list in a generic and elegant manner from **todays** month which means going backwards two years from today.

Thanks!

Comment: you mean generate such a list of tuples spanning 2 years, starting in the current month? what did you try?

Comment: @FObersteiner Yes, exactly. I tried creating such list by hand but it felt pretty sluggish so I wanted to get some python inspiration from here :)

Comment: @axox-ea Please [edit] this question and show what you tried and show the results. SO is not a code-writing service.